# Apply function to sequence

Tags: r, function

I have a vector:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

I need to calculate a vector, for example, with cumulative sum of squares:
`y <- c(a1, a2, a3...)` where: `a1 = 1^2`; `a2 = 1^2+2^2`; `a3 = 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2` and so on.

It is like "cumsum", but I need to calculate my function (not only sum of sqares, but any) like this.

Thank you!

Comment: Only FOR loop, but I'm sure, that it is the worst thing.

Comment: cumsum(x^2) - it's ok, but i wish to know, how to calculate more complex function, for example ln (x1*x2), ln(x1*x2*x3)... Is there a easy way to do it?

Comment: Hi Ilya, I updated my answer to show how you could generalize to more complex functions. Next time please include the purpose in your question ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First square the elements, than take the cumulative sum of that:

```
y <- cumsum(x^2)
```

Output:

```
1   5  14  30  55  91 140 204
```

---

For other functions such as `ln(x1*x2*...xn)`, you can often still do them efficiently. If that is not possible, you could use `sapply`, the following four are all equivalent in output:

```
log(cumprod(x))
sapply(cumprod(x), log)
sapply(cumprod(x), function(a) {log(a)})
sapply(1:8, function(i) {log(prod(x[1:i]))}) # not efficient.
```

However, note that the last one is computationally inefficient, since it calculates the product many times (first `x1`, then `x1*x2`, then `x1*x2*x3`, then `x1*x2*x3*x4` etc.), whereas the others use `cumprod`, which calculates `x1*x2`, and multiplies the output with `x3`, multiplies that output with `x4`, so the total number of multiplications is minimized. So always watch out that you are not over-complicating things.

Hope this helps!

Comment: One more question. Let I have a vector a<-(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5). I need a list: b<-list(a1, c(a1,a2), c(a1,a2,a3), c(a1,a2,a3,a4), c(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)). Is there a simple way?

Comment: Yes, you can use `lapply` instead of apply and do the following: `lapply(1:length(x), function(i) {x[1:i]})`

Comment: I'm really grateful to you!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice [reference](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) on this by Hadley Wickham in Advanced R.

Below is a code example

```
func <- function(x, myfun, ...) {
    cumsum(myfun(x, ...))
}

#examples
out <- func(1:8, `^`, e2=2)
identical(out, cumsum((1:8)^2))

identical(func(1:8, log), cumsum(log(1:8)))
```

Comment: You can do `func(1:8, `^`, 2)` i.e. backquote